# Issue using Ajax to change a user Password

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a strange issue while attempting to use Ajax to change a user's password on a site I am working on. Basically, I have a form where a user can input their username, old password, and their new password twice. From there JQuery takes over and makes an Ajax request (I have tried .post and .get with identical results) to a PHP Page. The PHP page performs basic error checking (making sure all fields are filled, that the new passwords match, and that the new password meets all complexity requirements), and then using simplexml_load_file() it makes a request to a web service (written in VB, the request is via URL with urlencoded get parameters, and returns XML) which actually changes the user password.

While making the request with passwords which do not meet the complexity requirements, the request to the web service is never called, and the Ajax request works just fine. While making the request with a form field missing, the same thing happens.

While making the request by directly accessing the PHP page with get parameters manually typed, everything works as planned.

The problem occurs when I attempt to use Ajax to make the request with good passwords and all fields filled. I receive the following error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: path-to/jquery-1.6.2.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 18" data: no]
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function makePasswordRequest() {
email = $("#email").val();
currentPassword = $("#currentPassword").val();
newPassword = $("#newPassword").val();
newPasswordRetype = $("#newPasswordRetype").val();
$.get("../changeUserPassword.php", { 
        "email": email, 
        "currentPassword": currentPassword, 
        "newPassword": newPassword, 
        "newPasswordRetype": newPasswordRetype 
    },
     function(data){
       if(data.PasswordChanged){
            $("#notificationArea").addClass("success");
       }
       else{
            $("#notificationArea").addClass("failure");
       }
       $("#notificationArea").html(data.MessageString);
     }, "json");
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#passwordChangeForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        makePasswordRequest();
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, folks I have solved the problem. The issue appears to be that the Web service was sending back some kind of object (which contained only a string), and while the JSON looked fine while accessing it directly, JavaScript couldn't parse it. I edited the code to pull the data at index 0 from each string-like object, and everything is working beautifully. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think the JSON object format is such that both the name and value should be quoted

```
   get("../changeUserPassword.php", { 
        "email": "email", 
        "currentPassword": "currentPassword", 
        "newPassword": "newPassword", 
        "newPasswordRetype": "newPasswordRetype" 
    },
```